# What bandwidth values should I set?

Tags: bandwidth, cloudflare, digital-ocean, alibaba-cloud

**Edit 1:** I gave the used bandwidth in DigitalOcean and CloudFlare in details. We could assume that other factors (like CPU, memory) remain the same. My question is about to ask the interpretation of the analysis of DO and CloudFlare, and the equivalence of bandwidth setting among different providers. Note that at least two big Chinese cloud providers (Alibaba Cloud and Baidu Cloud) have this configuration. It is not a duplicate of [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning). I have provided enough details for people who know bandwidth well.

---

I have a website, whose code is hosted by DigitalOcean (1GB Memory/20GB Disk/LON1, the bandwidth setting is not clear). I also use CloudFlare (free plan) on top of DigitalOcean to manage DNSs and caching, etc.

The website is currently blocked from Mainland China. One solution is to move its server to Hong Kong, then the website will be visitable from both western countries and Mainland China.

There are several choices for the server in a [Baidu Cloud](https://login.bce.baidu.com/?lang=en), one of the 3 big Chinese clouds:

1) "Elastic IP" and "prepay": in this case, I need to cet a **bandwidth value** / 公网带宽. My question is, according to the statistics below, how much bandwidth will be sufficient for my current website?

[image]

2) "Elastic IP" and "postpay": in this case, I need to choose "charge by network traffic" / 按使用流量计费 (where I need to set a **peak bandwidth value** / 带宽峰值) 
[image]
or "charge by bandwidth" / 按使用带宽计费 (where I need to set a **bandwidth value** / 公网带宽). 
[image]

Could anyone tell me which plan suits me best, and especially what value I should set?

PS: my website is not heavily visited, the visiting is quite regular. What I care most is the speed when one visitor loads the website.

Here is the statistics of CloudFlare for the last 24 hours:

[image] 
[image]

Here is the statistics of DigitalOcean for the last 24 hours:

[image]

Comment: Exactly where, in which service, is asking you to choose "pay standard" or "pay as you go"? I use EC2, CloudFlare, and an Elastic IP, and I have never had to fill out anything similar. Please edit your question to show where this question is asked, and comment so I can see your reply. When I googled those two terms this question was the first hit on Google.

Comment: I just find the english version of their website, though it is not fully english... I just edited the question... thank you...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

Comment: Ok, this wasn't about EC2 or DO, it was about Baidu Cloud. I've created the correct tag for you, it didn't exist before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'charge by network traffic' is better than 'charge by bandwidth' when ‘website is not heavily visited’.

If your traffic is busy all the time, you may need 'charge by bandwidth'.
Or, 'charge by bandwidth' is too expensive to you, and if you set a low bandwidth for saving money, it can't handle the peak sometime.

Comment: I also feel that 'charge by network traffic' may suit me better. But in this case, what "peak bandwidth value" I should set? `9Mbps` or `3Mbps`?

Comment: @Thomas Why not set 100Mbps or higher bandwidth when you using 'charge by network traffic'?

Comment: because higher bandwidth cost more money, so I'd better calculate how much I need...

Comment: @Thomas emm, under 'charge by network traffic' mode, the price for pre GB traffic should be same, no matter how much the peak bandwidth value you set, isn't it?

Comment: indeed, I just checked it, under 'charge by network traffic' mode, the price for pre GB traffic is the same, no matter how much the peak bandwidth value you set. And the maximum peak bandwidth value is `1000Mbps`. Then there will be no harm to set it `1000Mbps`?

Comment: I would not set it to 1000 Mbps. Based upon the numbers above 5 Mbps (or even 2 Mpbs) will be fine. The issue that I constantly see is that bad actors will consume way more bandwidth than regular uses. Give them 1000 Mpbs and that will cost you. This means having a firewall and creating rules to block the bad traffic.

Answer (score 0):

There are different types of plans that services like Alibaba offers, if you know how your server is going to be dealing with the traffic it gets you may outline a good estimate of how much it will cost you for different types of bandwidth plans.

You may take a look at the Pay-As-You-Go plans that Alibaba Cloud offers:
https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/25411.htm

The minimum charge for the lifecycle of an ECS instance (from creation to release) is USD 0.01.